SwiftUI TextFields in ForEach with Equatable Views Misbehave After Deletion
I'm developing a SwiftUI app where I display a list of items, each containing a TextField. Since editing the textfield in one of these items causes all item views to re-render, I opt'd to implement equatable on the item views to improve performance.
However, after deleting an item from the list, the TextField bindings seem to get confused. Specifically, when I edit a TextField after a deletion, the text updates in multiple fields simultaneously. This can also cause the following error if it tries to update a textfield that no longer exists: Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:675: Fatal error: Index out of range
Steps to reproduce the issue:

Run the code provided below.
Delete the item labeled "text 2" by tapping the "Delete" button next to it.
Tap on the "text 3" TextField and start typing.
Notice that both "text 3" and "text 4" TextFields update with the same text.
Now delete "text 3"
Now start typing in "text 4"
Notice the app crashes with an index out of range error

struct MyDataItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var text: String = ""
    var placeholder: String = ""
    
    static func == (lhs: MyDataItem, rhs: MyDataItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id &&
        lhs.text == rhs.text &&
        lhs.placeholder == rhs.placeholder
    }
}

struct BugPrepro: View {
    
    @State var data: [MyDataItem] = [
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 1"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 2"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 3"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 4")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($data, id: \.id) { $dataItem in
                LineItemView(dataItem: $dataItem, onDelete: {
                    data.removeAll { $0.id == dataItem.id }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LineItemView: View, Equatable {
    
    @Binding var dataItem: MyDataItem
    var onDelete: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(dataItem.placeholder, text: $dataItem.text)
            Button(action: onDelete) {
                Text("Delete")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .border(.black)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: LineItemView, rhs: LineItemView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.dataItem == rhs.dataItem
    }
}

My understanding:

MyDataItem conforms to Identifiable, so SwiftUI should track each item's identity.
By implementing Equatable on LineItemView, I'm trying to prevent unnecessary view updates to improve performance.
Despite this, deleting an item seems to cause the TextField bindings to overlap.

My question:
Why are the TextField bindings getting mixed up after deleting an item when using Equatable on the view? How can I prevent the views from unnecessarily re-rendering without causing this issue?

There is Zero need for an “Equatable View” ever. It is an attempt to circumvent what SwiftUI does well.

The performance issues I'm running into are because other LineItemView views are being re-rendered when the data within them has not changed . Do you have any other suggestions on how to address the performance issues? I was under the impression this is what an EquatableView was for. In my real app, these Line Item Views are rather complex, and cause a significant frame rate stutter with every character typed

That is the issue you should focus on. If I had to guess you are using ObservableObjects that are invalidating everything instead of targeted redrawing. SwiftUI has come a long way. Without an MRE for your use case we cant help you specifically.

It works when you remove Equatable from LineItemView (and the == function).

Amending my MRE above by removing the Equatable of LineItemView, the undefined behaviour no longer exists, however the performance concerns are still there. Each LineItemView is being re-rendered despite me only updating just one of the text fields - I can observe this with a simple print statement in the body. So without Equatable, how can I circumvent this behaviour? You can see I don't have any ObservableObjects that could invalidate the view

The body being called doesn't mean everything is being redrawn you can test this by adding an onAppear to the Text in the button or creating a subview and adding a print to that body and putting it in the Button or the body for LineItemView those second bodies won't  be called and you won't see a print for those. SwiftUI does best with small Views. 50 lines should be close to the max  IMO.

Another important thing is to only pass down in the arguments what is actually needed so when you create children the children aren't tied to the entire MyDataItem they would only be tied to the exact things they need.

Oh ok I see. Brilliant, thank you very much. I will look into this further to see what is actually the cause of my performance issues. Appreciate the clarification!

Using a UUID that gets regenerated each time for your Identifiable conformance is bad practice. It causes your objects to change IDs every time they are touched, which causes lots of undesirable side-effects.

Hi Duncan, I assumed these IDs would have been generated at instantiation, and in this case, would not change until the entire app restarts? Placing a let _ = print(dataItem.id) in the body of LineItemView appears to print the same UUID string each time I update a textfield. Is that not the case?

*would not change until the parent view is recreated

@BenzyNeez still crashes even if removing Equatable and the ==. Type into text 4 then delete text 4 then crash.

IMHO, it is crashing because you are deleting inside the loop.
That is why the usual .onDelete(perform: ...) has to be outside the
ForEach loop for it to work.

Oh, wow, at first, I thought it was the old Objective-C issue where you couldn't delete anything in a forEach loop, but it seems to be related to some internal SwiftUI optimization. I have played with it, and you can workaround the issue by moving @State var data to @StateObject
UPD. This fix issue is just for deletion,as @malhal has mentioned the crash is still there when interacting with TextField
import SwiftUI

struct MyDataItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var text: String = ""
    var placeholder: String = ""

    static func == (lhs: MyDataItem, rhs: MyDataItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id &&
        lhs.text == rhs.text &&
        lhs.placeholder == rhs.placeholder
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [MyDataItem] = [
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 1"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 2"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 3"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 4")
    ]
}

struct BugPrepro: View {

    @StateObject var model = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($model.data) { $dataItem in  // Use binding to pass to LineItemView
                LineItemView(dataItem: $dataItem) {
                    if let index = model.data.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == dataItem.id }) {
                        model.data.remove(at: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LineItemView: View {

    @Binding var dataItem: MyDataItem  // Use @Binding to enable updates
    var onDelete: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(dataItem.placeholder, text: $dataItem.text)  // Use binding for TextField
            Button(action: onDelete) {
                Text("Delete")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}

#Preview {
    BugPrepro()
}


yeah, @StateObject is more suitable here, thanks
updated

Still crashes. Type a letter into text 4, delete text 4, click text 3, crash. Also body is still called on every LineItemView no matter which text field is edited, which was his original performance concern. Part of the problem is @Binding calls body no matter when when a the View is init.

To stop the crashes and the TextField mixed up, you need
to move the deletion outside the ForEach loop.
Use .onChange to delete the idToDelete.
Example code
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        BugPrepro()
    }
}

struct MyDataItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String = ""
    var placeholder: String
}

struct BugPrepro: View {
    @State private var data: [MyDataItem] = [
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 1"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 2"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 3"),
        MyDataItem(placeholder: "text 4")
    ]
    
    @State private var idToDelete: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($data) { $dataItem in
                LineItemView(dataItem: $dataItem, onDelete: {
                    idToDelete = dataItem.id
                })
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: idToDelete) {
            data.removeAll { $0.id == idToDelete }
        }
    }
}

struct LineItemView: View {
    @Binding var dataItem: MyDataItem
    var onDelete: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(dataItem.placeholder, text: $dataItem.text)
            Button(action: onDelete) {
                Text("Delete")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .border(.black)
    }
}


Seems to me ForEach's automatic bindings feature is broken in this case of removing the last TextField and we have to wait for it to be fixed. It looks like it tries to end editing on the removed UITextField and crashes trying to update the binding that has gone. So in the meantime you can do it the old way which appears to work ok:
ForEach(data) { dataItem in 
    let binding = Binding<MyDataItem> { // fyi when you init a Binding it immediately calls the get closure to save the value.
        item
    } set: { newValue in
        if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { i in
            i.id == item.id
        }) {
            data[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    LineItemView(dataItem: binding) {

As for the performance issue of every LineItemView's body being called no matter which text is changed, I believe your Equatable implementation is correct - so basically you are trying to make it ignore the onDelete closure which it can't compare automatically.
I submitted Feedback FB15573786 and linked here.
